# My layout isn't loading in my Magento admin view

Tags: magento

Here's my controller

```
<?php
class Desbest_Brands_Adminhtml_BrandController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_action {
    public function indexAction() {
        //echo "showing 123 works!";
        $this->loadLayout(); $this->renderLayout();
    }
```

And here's my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="1.0.0">
<brands_adminhtml_brand_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="brands/adminhtml_brand" name="brand" />
        <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="left.newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</brands_adminhtml_brand_index>
</layout>
```

Yet nothing loads up when I show the view in my admin, not even the email subscribe form.

Comment: Does `echo "showing 123 works!";` display something when not commented ?

Comment: The cache is off. Yes it does display something. It takes up the whole white page with 123 on it and nothing else.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If your action is called correctly (echo 123 shown), other than cache issue, there might be something's wrong with your handle.

In your action, try to put this code after `$this->loadLayout()` :

```
var_dump(Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->getUpdate()->getHandles());
die();
```

It will show all the handles loaded for that request.

The handle is generated from fullActionName, in simple way, we can say that it is generated as:

```
route + controller + action
```

Take a look at your config.xml.

If your config.xml like:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <brands>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Desbest_Brands</module>
                <frontName>brands</frontName>
            </args>
        </brands>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

For your action, it will generate handle: `<brands_adminhtml_brand_index>`

If your config.xml like:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <brandsadmin>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Desbest_Brands</module>
                <frontName>brands</frontName>
            </args>
        </brandsadmin>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

For your action, it will generate handle: `<brandsadmin_adminhtml_brand_index>`

Update:

And don't forget to define your admin layout in your config.xml, eg:

```
<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <brandsadmin>
                <file>yourlayoutname.xml</file>
            </brandsadmin>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>
```

Put it under app/design/adminhtml/default/[default/youradmintheme]/layout/yourlayoutname.xml

Comment: My config.xml looks like this, and it still doesn't work. https://gist.github.com/028124ba4b022b0685e2 http://imm.io/zNow And my handle is `brands_adminhtml_brand_index`

Comment: It still doesn't work. I've updated my config.xml to be https://gist.github.com/028124ba4b022b0685e2/90b2eacc67482c90b432adf5cacf0b5f63d0dc9a and I'm still getting the blank page. I put my `adminlayout.xml` layout file in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/Desbest_Brands`

Comment: Try to echo something in your constructor's block, if it is shown up, it means your layout is called. For your example, nothings shown up because newsletter/subscribe.phtml is not exist, remember it is admin's template, not frontend

Comment: How do I echo something in the constructor's block? All I see are xml files.

Comment: My bad, your config for layout should be <file> not <files>.

Comment: Now my layout block is empty but I get an error that says `Fatal error: Call to a member function setSaveParametersInSession() on a non-object in /home/desbest/public_html/clients/magentofull/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Container.php on line 66` when my `Brand.php` block file is empty. https://gist.github.com/c682ce43205f984ff92c

Comment: That's good, it means your layout has been loaded. I don't know what are you going to create with that block. You need to create file named Grid.php under app/code/local/Desbest/Brands/Block/Adminhtml/Brand/. The Brand.php is extending from Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container and it will automatically looking for Grid.php, for the exact structure, you can see it in Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container line 66

Comment: I tried `class Desbest_Brands_Block_Adminhtml_Brand_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid` for Grid.php and it ending with `Grid_Container` and I got the error of `Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container' not found in`

Comment: Too hard to see what have you done so far, you can read it http://codemagento.com/2011/02/grids-and-forms-in-the-admin-panel/ section "The Grid Block"

Comment: I tried that, and I'm getting `Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container' not found in `app/code/local/Desbest/Brands/Block/Adminhtml/Brand.php` and the php file's only contents is `<?php
 
class Desbest_Brands_Block_Adminhtml_Brand extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{ }`

Comment: Ok, post your code as many as you can, I'll take a look at it

Comment: Here it is. I put it in a video screencast for easy understanding. **Part 1** http://www.screenr.com/fmz8 **Part 2** http://www.screenr.com/3mz8

Comment: Commented on your video. An empty Brand.php should trigger error message: Fatal error: Call to a member function setSaveParametersInSession() on a non-object in /home/desbest/public_html/clients/magentofull/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block‌​/Widget/Grid/Container.php on line 66 like you said before. Don't know what have you done so that the error message changed into Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container' not found in app/code/local/Desbest/Brands/Block/Adminhtml/Brand.php`

Comment: It looks like I had modified the actual Magento files without realising what I did earlier on. So I reinstalled Magento and did the module making again, and it's starting to work more. But now I'm just getting this error. `Fatal error: Call to a member function setSaveParametersInSession() on a non-object in /home/desbest/public_html/clients/magentofull/app/code/local/Desbest/Brands/Block/Adminhtml/Brand.php on line 22` for this file. https://gist.github.com/3c41d229046f768f9151

Comment: you need to create app/code/local/Desbest/Brands/Block/Adminhtml/Brand/Grid.php

Comment: I'm too having the same problem. but still my layout not loading. the problem i found there is, my code is not creating block for `grid container`. In my controller I'd written this code: `$this->loadLayout(); $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('sublogin/adminhtml_sublogin'); $this->_addContent($block); $this->renderLayout();` My file structure for this `Sublogin.php` is: `app/code/local/Excellence/Sublogin/Block/Adminhtml/Sublogin.php` and it extends `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container`.